# jQuery selector: How to choose another element in a parent div

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I need to find a div in my HTML called `.detailsBox` with jQuery.  The div, which is one of a series of divs all with the same class name output in a loop, is going to be slid down when a link is clicked.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="support">
    <h2><a href="#" class="title"><?php echo $growing->title; ?></a></h2>  <!-- Click on this link... -->

    <div class="detailsBox">  <-- ... and this div will slide down from being hidden -->
        <div id="tabs-text">
            <p class="description"><?php echo $growing->description; ?></p>
        </div>

        <div id="learnmore">  
            <a class="sendEmail" target="_blank" id="<?php echo $growing->link;?>" href="<?php echo base_url() . 'channel-partners/tools/' . $growing->link; ?>"><?php echo $growing->link_text; ?></a>      
            <a class="sendEmail" id="<?php echo $growing->link2;?>"  href="<?php echo $growing->link2; ?>"><?php echo $growing->link_text2; ?></a>   
       </div>

    </div>
 </div>
```

I can find the parent div like this:

```
var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
```

But I need a way to then find the child `.detailsBox`.  How do I do that.  I tried this and it didn't work:

```
$(parent + '> div.detailsBox').slideDown();
```

The console complains that this is an unrecognized expression because I am trying to combine an object and a string.  How do I make the whole thing a selector wrapped in jQuery?

Comment: The latter two lines happen within a click event for `$('.title')`.

Comment: `$(this).closest('div').find('.detailsBox').slideDown();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `parent.children('.detailsBox').slideDown();`

The `parent()` returns a jQuery object so you have the methods off that object.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass parent as the context parameter in jquery, ie.

```
$('div.detailsBox', $(parent)).slideDown();
```

Comment: `parent` is already a jquery object as per OP's example, otherwise good solution.

Comment: Interesting approach.  I didn't know you could pass context in selector.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `parent.find(".detailsBox")`. However I always recommend prefixing jquery objects with the $ sign, i.e. `var $parent = $(...)`

Comment: Is this a best practice?  I've seen this before but was never quite sure why people did it.  Is it just for clarity?

Comment: I wouldn't champion it as "best practice", but rather "good practice" because it helps me to tell apart objects and simple variables. I'd use, say, `var h = $(this).height` but `var $sib = $(this).siblings("div")` for example ;) It makes a lot more sense especially when you are appending jQuery methods to jQuery objects, like `$sib.addClass("item")` or `$sib.hide()`.